# $ \sin(x) \simeq \tan(x) $ when $ x \rightarrow 0 $ - Maclaurin series

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion, education

I'm wondering if it is correct to say that:

$$ \sin(x) \simeq \tan(x) \quad \text{when} \quad  x \rightarrow 0 $$

because, according to Maclaurin series:

$$ \sin(x) \simeq x \quad \text{when} \quad  x \rightarrow 0 $$

and

$$ \tan(x) \simeq x \quad \text{when} \quad  x \rightarrow 0 $$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, it is not correct, because $\:\simeq\:$ is the symbol for *isomorphic to*….

Comment: You don't need anything fancy. $\sin(x)/\tan(x) \to 1$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: For asymptotic equality, use the symbol $\sim$.

Comment: @Bernard In the nonstandard analysis text I used, that symbol was used for what is intuitively differing by an infinitesimal at most. More formally, if we let $R$ be the nonstandard reals (which includes the reals), then $x\simeq y \iff |x-y| \le \varepsilon \; \forall \varepsilon \in R$.

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidPeterson

Comment: Hi @Bernard is the symbol $ \simeq $ equivalent to $\cong$?

Comment: More or less. If depends on authors. The symbol for *equivalent* is just `\sim` (and it's shorter to type). This being said, it is correct, because equivalence of functions at a point is indeed an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\frac{\sin x}{\tan x}=\cos x\to1$ as $x\to0$, $\sin x\sim\tan x$ (sources differ on whether to use $\sim$ or $\simeq$).

Comment: Hello @J.G. thank you for your reply.